# Angular Material: Custom Form Field Control - move floating label (down)

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors, angular-material

I've created a *Custom Form Field Control* for Angular 8 compatible with **Reactive Forms** and **Angular Material**. However, it being a *simplified* **Rich-Text Editor**, it has a header with various buttons with actions for the user.

How can I move the **Placeholder label below the header** of my input control to the actual textarea?

[Current placeholder label placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU93b.jpg)

Comment: Other than on or off, there is no option for the position of the floating placeholder.

Comment: @G.Tranter Thanks. Guess I'll have to experiment a bit and see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since nobody really responded to my question, I'll post my own solution to this problem, one cruder (Solution 2) and one I deem proper (Solution 2, though to me it appears otherwise).

## Edit: Solution 2: Proper approach

Well, I tried to make my code slightly more-configurable, hence I made one little mistake when changing code - I changed one variable to *static*, a variable used to declare the ID MatFormField uses in a class definition inside itself which we can use to customize the look of our component.

Namely `controlType`. Using this variable, we can identify when our component is in-use by direct class name following naming convention `mat-form-field-type-<controlType>`. So, since my `controlType = "app-text-editor"`, I can use it like this:

```css
.mat-form-field-type-app-text-editor:not(.mat-form-field-should-float) .mat-form-field-label-wrapper > .mat-form-field-label {
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    padding: .5em;
}
```

## Original: Solution 1: Hacky-approach

What I did was change my component to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, used the selector of my component inside css as my main identifier (in my case: `app-text-editor`) and then used **CSS Sibling** selector to select the **floating label** and **placeholder** to set offset for my *TextEditor* header and reset it back to default once the label is floating. The **resulting CSS** looks like this:

```
app-text-editor {
  // Styling for actual TextEditor

  &.floating ~ .mat-form-field-label-wrapper > .mat-form-field-label {
    margin-top: initial;
    padding: initial;
  }
  & ~ .mat-form-field-label-wrapper > .mat-form-field-label {
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    padding: .5em; // Used to properly align the content inside my contenteditable
}
```

Or as **pure CSS** would look like:

```css
app-text-editor.floating ~ .mat-form-field-label-wrapper > .mat-form-field-label {
  margin-top: initial;
  padding: initial;
}
app-text-editor ~ .mat-form-field-label-wrapper > .mat-form-field-label {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  padding: .5em; /* Used to properly align the content inside my contenteditable */
}
```

Weirdly enough, even the animation transition looks smooth despite me using such a hacky-approach for repositioning it.

If you don't mind using advanced CSS selector ([Can I Use: *Advanced CSS3 selectors*](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)), the solution can be even cleaner:

**SCSS**:

```
app-text-editor {
  // Styling for the actual TextEditor

  &:not(.floating) ~ .mat-form-field-label-wrapper > .mat-form-field-label {
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    padding: .5em; // Used to properly align the content inside my contenteditable
}
```

**Pure CSS**:

```css
app-text-editor:not(.floating) ~ .mat-form-field-label-wrapper > .mat-form-field-label {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  padding: .5em; /* Used to properly align the content inside my contenteditable */
}
```